# Regular expression to avoid a set of characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string, validation

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and I would like to validate a class attribute just to avoid to store in the database a string containing these characters:  (blank space), `<`, `>`, `"`, `#`, `%`, `{`, `}`, `|`, `\`, `^`, `~`, `[`, `]` and ```.

**What is the regex?**

Comment: @Octopus-Paul: the `]` will end the character class, and the `\s` sequence does not work inside a character class.

Comment: @Porges `\s` works just fine inside a character class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it should also be non-empty:

```
^[^\] ><"#%{}|\\^~\[`]+$
```

Since someone is downvoting this, here is some test code:

```
ary = [' ', '<', '>', '"', '#', '%', '{', '}', '|', '\\', '^', '~', '[', ']', '`', 'a']
ary.each do |i|
  puts i =~ /^[^\] ><"#%{}|\\^~\[`]+$/
end
```

Output:

```
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
nil
0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = "foobar"
b = "foo ` bar"

re = /[ \^<>"#%\{\}\|\\~\[\]\`]/

a =~ re # => nil
b =~ re # => 3
```

The inverse expression is:

```
/\A[^ \^<>"#%\{\}\|\\~\[\]\`]+\Z/
```

Comment: Except my "b" above?  The regex returns a truthy value for bad strings and `nil` for good ones, so you need to inverse the logic.

Comment: Note that there is a sort of inverse of `=~` available, which is `!~`. Like `b !~ re # => false`.

Comment: I need to use the regex in a Ruby on Rails `validates_format_of` method. So, *how can I properly use your regex to make what I would like to accomplish?*

Comment: @user502052 /\A[^ \^<>"#%\{\}\|\\~\[\]\`]+\Z/

Comment: Edited the answer, as I can't format the pattern in a comment due to the backtick.

Comment: Oops, pasted @Porges' expression the first time by accident as I was playing in IRB :P

Comment: I get the `premature end of char-class: /\A[^ \^<>"#%\{\}\|\\~[]`]+\Z/` error. I am running `ruby-1.9.2-p290`.

Answer (score 2):

```
bad_chars = %w(< > " # % { } | \ ^ ~ [ ] ')
re = Regexp.union(bad_chars)
p %q(hoh'oho) =~ re #=> 3
```

`Regexp.union` takes care of escaping.